# Java Auto detect encoding an http response body

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have program that downloads webpages and process the body, and I am having problem detecting the encoding for some pages, especially if there is no information added in the header or in the html content, is there a way in java to auto detect and evaluate the char encoding of String or html body of a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [juniversalchardet](https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/), which is the Java port of encoding detector library of Mozilla.

Here is a sample program to check if the encoding is UTF-8.

```
protected static boolean validUTF8(byte[] input) { 
  UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null); 
  detector.handleData(input, 0, input.length); 
  detector.dataEnd(); 
  if ("UTF-8".equals(detector.getDetectedCharset())) { 
   return true; 
  } 
  return false; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer I would suggest:
[`URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(InputStream is)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) but *the Stream must support marking,* and
[`guessContentTypeFromName(String fname)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName%28java.lang.String%29) (yes, I know it sounds silly, but it is very efficient).

Of course, first you have to get the Stream for the body of the HttpURLConnection somewhat like this `InputStream is = response.getInputStream();`